# ApostropheCMS Moog Type - Extend your own Custom Module

Tags: apostrophe-cms

## Extend your own Module

This question is basically a good question for a beginner who just new to OOP language. I found your code [here](https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/intermediate/forms.html#going-deeper-with-apostrophe-creating-a-code-contact-form-code-module) said that extending module using afterConstruct is a good practice. Can you teach us how to **EXTEND** it from other module and **IMPLEMENT** the extended method from other module ? I followed your example when building my Own Contact Form Module here :

```js
  afterConstruct: function(self) {
    self.setSubmitSchema();
  },

  construct: function(self, options) {

    self.setSubmitSchema = function() {
      self.submitSchema = self.apos.schemas.subset(self.schema,
        [ 'name', 'email', 'title', 'body' ]
      );
    };
```

Below is my point of view of using Moog Type , are those correct ?

> **construct** -> every method ATTACHED to the construct . **beforeConstruct** -> Only applicable if you extending options like *addFields* , *removeFields* and *alterFields* to it. *afterConstruct* -> Applicable for EXTENDING module/method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is too general, but what you need is a good example of this being done correctly.

For that, just look at any pieces module we've implemented, for instance look at [apostrophe-redirects](https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-redirects/blob/master/index.js), which extends pieces, adding a `beforeSave` method override to do something custom.

See also the [apostrophe-samples](https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-samples) project which contains several examples of pieces modules with overrides. Again, these extend `apostrophe-pieces`, so they demonstrate what you are asking about.

Regarding the three functions:

`beforeConstruct` is for adjusting `options` first before the module you're extending gets to see it. Useful when a subclass needs to add fields to `addFields`, for instance.

`construct` is for attaching methods to `self`.

And `afterConstruct` is for initialization, accomplished by invoking some of those methods. This is the right time because subclass modules have had a chance to override some of those methods before `afterConstruct` runs.

Comment: Thank youuu for that explanation . Oh btw, yeah,  I can see that every piece extend `apostrophe-pieces` . But if let say I would like to extend my own contact form module, should I done it like this? `extend : contact-form` . I don't have to extend `apostrophe-pieces` again,  correct? Because that contact form module already has one. Can it be extend more? Make it an array?

Comment: Each module extends one and only one module, from which it inherits behavior. You can extend any module you want, including your own contact-form module for instance, if you want to make a new module which is mostly the same but overrides some options and methods. They are then independent and can both be activated in app.js. This is like how classes work in Java or PHP etc.

Comment: Yes any number of modules may extend the same "parent class" module. And they inherit whatever behavior it has, including whatever it inherited from its parent. Any module that does not explicitly extend another extends `apostrophe-module`, which is where methods like `render` and `pushAsset` come from.